# Function parameter object destructuring results in undefined variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am running Node v6.6.0, which has support for destructuring function arguments:

```
function foo ({ a: { b }}) {
  // stuff
}
```

Suppose I want to destructure *and access both `a` and `b`*. Sadly the following **doesn't** seem to work:

```
function foo ({ a: { b }}) {
  return [a, b]
}
foo({ a: { b: 123 }})
// ReferenceError: a is not defined!
```

Is this bug in Node or is this the expected behavior for ES6? Shouldn't both `a` and `b` be defined in the function? If not, why does destructuring have the effect of un-defining a base property name (`a`)?

Is there a way I can *use parameter destructuring* to get both `a` and `b` defined in the function? I'm explicitly trying to avoid manually destructuring them.

Comment: `a` merely designates what property of the parameter `b` is to be taken from. It is not defined or accessible as a parameter. If you want to access `a`, you will have to extract `b` yourself within the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this bug in Node or is this the expected behavior for ES6?

This is expected behaviour. Because `{a: {b}}` doesn't bind `a` as a name it just indicates you want to access `a` property of the destructured object.

You could use the following.

```js
function foo ({ a, a: {b} }) {
  return [a, b]
}
console.log(foo({ a: { b: 123 }}))
```

Comment: Ah, so simple! That didn't even cross my mind as a possibility. Thanks!